# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone' in zone.d.ts file after update angular to version ^12

Tags: angular, typescript, duplicates, node-modules, identifier

after updating angular version v11 to latest ^v12 I received the following error,I was looking for duplicate node_modules folder but ... couldn`t found anything.

[image]

Comment: How did you update?

Comment: I did all the steps from https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0

Comment: I think there might be an incorrect import somewhere. Maybe you import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js" somewhere and 'zone.js' somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks.The problem was in src/main.ts file.There zone.js was imported as import 'zone.js' so I'm changed to import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer.

The error is caused by incorrect `import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'` somewhere.

Zone should be imported only once. Usually in `polyfills.ts`.

The best way to import is simply `import 'zone.js'`.

In you project, try to search for the longer import and remove it.